# React-Table Column Headers Displaying Vertically

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am using the React-Table module to create a table. So far I have the following:

```
<div>
    <ReactTable
    columns={[{columns :
        [{
          Header: "Time",
          accessor: "time", //name of field in table
        },
        {
          Header: "Weight",
          accessor: "weight",
        }
      ]}]}
    />
</div>
```

However, my column headers are displaying vertically like this:

Time

Weight

I would like them to display horizontally as expected.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v6) each column header is an array of objects, so each object you pass to it will have a header that displays horizontally. In your example you are only passing the columns prop one object, try to arrange it more like the documentation example:

```
 const columns = [{
        Header: 'Name',
        accessor: 'name' // String-based value accessors!
      }, {
        Header: 'Age',
        accessor: 'age',
        Cell: props => <span className='number'>{props.value}</span> // Custom cell components!
      }, {
        id: 'friendName', // Required because our accessor is not a string
        Header: 'Friend Name',
        accessor: d => d.friend.name // Custom value accessors!
      }, {
        Header: props => <span>Friend Age</span>, // Custom header components!
        a

ccessor: 'friend.age'
  }]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response; it didn't work though. I am putting this code inside of a component. Is it possible that the css of the component is overriding the react-table css?

Comment: It's possible, but highly unlikely, can you recreate your code in a sandbox. For example https://codesandbox.io/, than post the link and I can try to help

Comment: Thanks for your response! I ended up using bootstrap tables instead and it worked fine.